# Passing 2 values from text form to another page through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, variables

I have a text form that contains a text field as well as a designated ID number that i would like to send over to another page. Would that be possible ?

```
<form name="cForm" id="cForm">
            Comment: <input type="textBox" name="cText" id="cText" />
            <input type="button" name="submitCreate" id="submitCreate" value="Create" onclick="showCreate('.$row['ID'].')" /><br>
        </form>

<script>
function showCreate(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("showCreate").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("showCreate").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("Post","showCreate.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

i would like to get the value of the text field and ID in separate variables as such

```
$comment = $_REQUEST["q"];
$ID = $_REQUEST["p"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure that i understand you right but try this:

```
<form name="cForm" id="cForm">
            Comment: <input type="textBox" name="cText" id="cText" />
            <input type="button" name="submitCreate" id="submitCreate" value="Create" onclick="showCreate('.$row['ID'].')" /><br>
        </form>

<script>
    function showCreate(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        $("#showCreate").html("");
        return;
      } 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "showCreate.php",
        data: "q="+str+"&p="+$("#cText").val()
        }).done(function( result ) {
             $("#showCreate").html(result);
        });
    }
</script>
```

so you gonna be able to use vars at php like  you wanted

```
$comment = $_REQUEST["q"];
$ID = $_REQUEST["p"];
```

Comment: hi @volkinc i have got an `Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined `for this `"q="+s+"&p="+$("#cText").val()` is there a need for the `s` inside ?

Comment: sorry. it typo. s = str. the war that you pass to the function